# Make the inbox indicator more visible

Tags: feature-request, design, notifications, top-bar

I have trouble noticing that I have inbox notifications. I am not refering to its position, but to its appearance. The inbox indicator in the top bar feels a lot smaller and less contrasted than the old one. They have the same color, but the new one is smaller and I think its placement makes it more discrete.

Old: [image: old indicator]
    
New: [image: new indicator]

Side by side in isolation the difference doesn't seem so much, but the old one is a bit bigger, and it's alone in the bar rather than superposed over the <strike>square bra</strike> in-tray graphic, which makes it stand out a lot more.

Old CSS:

```
.topbar .icon-inbox .unread-count {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 9px;
    text-indent: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
}
```

New CSS:

```
.top-bar .indicator-badge {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #242729;
}
```

The old one has 10% bigger text and twice as much horizontal padding. That makes it a lot more visible.

Please make the inbox indicator stand out as much as the old one.

(No, this is [not a new complaint](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343830/make-the-indicator-of-unread-inbox-messages-more-visible). I've tried the new top bar style for a few days, and it isn't getting any better. This is not a matter of my getting used to it. The thing is just too small and poorly contrasted.)

Comment: I don't think we need it any bigger. I find it a nice thing that the number doesn't hide the whole icon as it used to do before.

Comment: When there's something to show I'd much rather that both the inbox and achievements be replaced by a red or green rectangle with a number in it, instead of trying to integrate the number into the icon (which is fragile in the face of font scaling).